How can we obtain the sublocality for the United States? I've tried, but it returns null for the USA, while I can get the sublocality for India

val geocoder = Geocoder(this@MapFragment.requireContext(), Locale.US)

            val addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)

            if (addresses!!.size > 0) {

                val address = addresses[0]

                Log.d("sdfsdfsdfdfds", "${address.subLocality}")

}


We tried to change Locale.getDefault() but still not getting sublocality for the USA. For the USA have a neighborhood. how we solve this.
val geocoder = Geocoder(this@MapFragment.requireContext(), Locale.US)
        val addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)

        if (addresses!!.size > 0) {

            val address = addresses[0]

            Log.d("sdfsdfsdfdfds", "${address.subLocality}")

}
